# I want to know the count of the repeated value in the result in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

For Example

```
ID      payment  
12345    Cash
12345    Cash
12345    Cash
12345    Cash
12345    Cash
56789    CC
56789    cc
56789    cc
```

I want the result like below

```
ID      payment   Seq No
12345    Cash      1
12345    Cash      2
12345    Cash      3
12345    Cash      4
12345    Cash      5
56789    CC        1
56789    cc        2
56789    cc        3
```

Comment: How does the title relate to the question a count is not a seq no..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try running below command.

```
select ID Payment, count (*) from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select id, payment,
       row_number() over (partition by payment order by id) as seq_num
from t;
```

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  If you want the sequence numbers in a particular order, then replace `id` in the `order by` with the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Thank you. But in my query I get the payment from another sub query. In that case what should I do?

Comment: @bhuvanabaskaran . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, database tag, and explanation.